# Why are Chrome DevTools shortcuts not working for me?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am using this guide for shortcuts: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/shortcuts

Now inside the sources panel, there are shortcuts like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> to 'Delete individual words' and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + `:number` to Jump to a line number. None of these seem to work. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

My cursor is inside the second function keyword. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> should delete the word but what actually happens is that my cursor change to `crosshair`. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortcut to delete individual words is actually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>, not <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>. The documentation appears to be wrong. I have now logged this as an issue to the `WebFundamentals` project: https://github.com/google/WebFundamentals/issues/2879

The shortcut to jump to a particular line number is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, then type `:number` (remember the colon first), and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Is there any place where I can get correct shortcuts?

Comment: @SanJeetSingh I have created a pull request for the issue above, with a fix to the incorrect shortcut. If you find others that are incorrect, you can log an issue on that repo if you have a GitHub account, otherwise I can do it for you.